# Convert fiscal year dates into calendar dates in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have data that looks a bit like this:

```r
fydates <- c("apr_20","jun_20","jul_21","aug_21","dec_23","jan_23","dec_24","jan_24")
```

The years in this list are actually the fiscal year but I want them to reflect the calendar year instead. So for every month between jan and jun the year number should stay the same, but for every month between jul and dec, the year should be the one before.

I.e. the same dates should be:

```r
realdates <- c("apr_20","jun_20","jul_20","aug_20","dec_22","jan_23","dec_23","jan_24")
```

Is there any way to make this happen please?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")

my(fydates) %>%
  if_else(month(.) > 6, . - years(1), .) %>%
  strftime("%b_%y")

# [1] "Apr_20" "Jun_20" "Jul_20" "Aug_20" "Dec_22" "Jan_23" "Dec_23" "Jan_24"
```